# How to get components by a particular Schema in TBB

Tags: templating, content-manager

I am new to template building blocks. I need to get all the components from a publication based on a particular schema inside a .Net TBB.

Can you please help me with the piece of code.

## update

I applied @Andreys solution. But some how it is returning all the Components. Here is my code. Can you please take a look?

```
Page page = page = _utilities.GetPage(); 
Publication publication = GetPublication(page); 
Component component = page.ComponentPresentations[0].Component; 
Schema videoSchema = (Schema)_engine.GetObject(component.Schema.Id); 
var filter = new OrganizationalItemItemsFilter(_engine.GetSession()); 
filter.Recursive = true; 
filter.ItemTypes = new[] { ItemType.Component }; 
filter.BasedOnSchemas = new[] { videoSchema }; 
var components = publication.RootFolder.GetItems(filter);
```

Answer (score 4):

The code provided by Saurabh is using the obsolete `Filter` class. Here's the better way:

```
var filter = new OrganizationalItemItemsFilter(session);
filter.Recursive = true;
filter.ItemTypes = new[] { ItemType.Component };
filter.BasedOnSchemas = new[] { schema };

var components = publication.RootFolder.GetItems(filter);
```

This way is a also a tiny bit lighter, as there can't be components in Strucuture Groups or in Categories, it does make sense to look only in the Building Blocks folder.

Comment: I applied your solution. But some how it is returning all the components. Here is my code. Can you please take a look...

Comment: Page page = page = _utilities.GetPage();
            Publication publication = GetPublication(page);

            Component component = page.ComponentPresentations[0].Component;

            Schema videoSchema = (Schema)_engine.GetObject(component.Schema.Id);

            var filter = new OrganizationalItemItemsFilter(_engine.GetSession());
            filter.Recursive = true;
            filter.ItemTypes = new[] { ItemType.Component };
            filter.BasedOnSchemas = new[] { videoSchema };


            var components = publication.RootFolder.GetItems(filter);

Answer (score 2):

I've used some code like below long time back, hope this helps.

```
                Filter fltr = new Filter();
                fltr.Conditions["Recursive"] = "true";
                fltr.Conditions["ItemType"] = ItemType.Component;
                fltr.Conditions["BasedOnSchema"] = "{tcmId of schema}";
                var components = publication.GetItems(fltr);
```

I copied this code from version 2009 days. So yeah as Andrey mentioned in his answer, the the Filter Class is Obselete now. So use `OrganizationalItemItemsFilter` if your tridion version is higher than 2009.